# Trying to pass URL from EditText to Fragment

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I am trying to pass a String value "url" to a fragment to display it in a web view. I keep getting the following error:

**java.lang.NullPointerException**

This is my code:

```
protected void goToTab1View() {
    if(mTabState != TAB1_STATE){
        mTabState = TAB1_STATE;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "goToTabView1: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if(fm!= null){
            //Perform fragment transaction
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            FragTab1 f = new FragTab1();
            f.setString(url);
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, f);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I presume I am not attaching the fragment correctly?? I am only new to fragments so I apologize if the question is obvious. Any help would be much appreciated.

STACK TRACE:

```
 01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at com.example.tabdemo.FragTab1.setString(FragTab1.java:57)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at com.example.tabdemo.TabFragment.goToTab1View(TabFragment.java:60)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at com.example.tabdemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-11 13:16:06.671: E/AndroidRuntime(23045):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should really specify what line and variable is causing the nullpointer. This is by far the easiest to find out by you with debugging.

Comment: @nandeesh I posted the error messages from stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are displaying Toast inside `setString()` of `FragTab1` Fragment. That is why you are facing the `NullPointerException`.

Remove Toast Display inside `setString()` of `FragTab1` and run the app it will work for you.

Until and unless FragTab1 is attached to Fragment Container, you don't get `getActivity()` which you are accessing before replacing the FragTab1 Fragment by setting the String as below

```
f.setString(url);
```

This will call the FragTab1's setString() where you are showing the Toast which will cause the NullPointerException as it couldn't get the Context.

Comment: @Javacadabra accept the answer so that it will helpful for others.

Comment: I will, I have to wait 5 minutes though.